# C# - Word interop get Excel table(Excel worksheet)

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, interop

After searching the whole day i still can't find how to access worksheet inside a word file.

I am using this code to open the file:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
appWord.Visible = false;

wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(General.GetInvoicePath(invoices[currentItem.Index]).Replace('/', '\\'));
```

Now you can use wordDocument.Tables to access all tables but not the EXCEL table.

This is the kind of object/table that I am trying to get in c#

[image]

I have used many ways to try and find it:

```
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Content.Tables.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Content.SmartTags.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Content.Frames.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Content.XMLNodes.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.XMLNodes.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Tables.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.TablesOfContents.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.TablesOfAuthorities.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.TablesOfFigures.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Subdocuments.Count);
Console.WriteLine("TEST :" + wordDocument.Content.Subdocuments.Count);
```

Comment: It “should” be possible to interact with the object by “activating” it and getting the Workbook object. Have a look here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/85ef2249-0344-42f5-8dec-e7c09f98c62b/extract-embedded-document-with-the-word-document?forum=vsto

Comment: @blins Thanks that is it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InlineShape embeddedWorkbook = wordDocument.InlineShapes[1];
embeddedWorkbook.OLEFormat.Activate();
Workbook workbook = (Workbook)embeddedWorkbook.OLEFormat.Object;

var cellValue = (string)(workbook.Sheets[1].Cells[6, 17] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value;

Console.WriteLine(cellValue);
```

This is the final solution to access the worksheet and get a cell value.

Answer (score 0):

An excel table in a word document is an OLE embedded object, not a native word element. You definitely can enumerate, add or delete such objects, but I am not sure if any interaction is possible. They are `InlineShapes`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinlineshapetype?view=word-pia see embedded an inline OLE objects in the enumeration.